# Android: How to draw vector drawables?

Tags: android, xml, vector, drawable

Is there a tutorial on creating vector drawables? I have no idea how the math behind paths, vectors, groups etc works, nor even understand what the values mean. Is there a graph? Is there a tool that lets you draw stuff on a graph? If I'm looking at a messenger text bubble, how would I proceed to know how to code the various parts of the bubble (especially the tail)?

Comment: Figma or Sketch? although there should be more simple software out there.

Comment: So it's not common for people to code their own drawables?

Comment: I don't think so. either UI designer provides it or you download it from somewhere.

Comment: AFAIK you would not manually create vector drawables but export them from a program like figma, illustrator, etc.